# How to convert configure apache2 to handle https

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, https

I have a site which is already running in http. I want to enable https for the full website.

I followed the tutorial on [this site](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/10/enable-self-signed-ssl-certificates-apache2-ubuntu-14-04/)

This is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf file

```
    IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            websitename websitename.com:443

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
            # modules, e.g.
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn
```

Now when I try to restart apache I get the following error.

```
   * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                 * 
   * The apache2 configtest failed.
    Output of config test was:
    AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:
    Invalid command 'websitename', perhaps misspelled or defined by a  module not included in the server configuration
    Action 'configtest' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `websitename` by `ServerName`

And you might also need to add port 443 to `Listen` and `NameVirtualHost`

See [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts)